Excitation = Exciton?
I have a question regarding optical excitations: Do all optical excitations result in the formation of excitons? Specifically, I'm curious about the scenarios involving molecules with chromophores (like porphyrins or perylene) and helium atom. Is the concept of excitons only applicable in solids (semiconductors and insulators), or does it extend to other systems as well?

I have heard people use the language of "excitons" when referring to any photoexcitation of electrons/holes in a solid. This wouldn't be my choice. An exciton is a bound interaction between the electron and its hole. It has a lower energy than the lowest conduction band state, and it is often observable through photoluminescence (at a wavelength longer than what's needed to excite the electron-hole pair) as the pair recombines.
Not every material demonstrates these exciton-specific properties. It's not to say that there is no interaction between excited electrons and holes, it's just that in many cases the interaction is weak, and the physics of excitons is not needed to adequately explain observations. Certainly, excitations in metals and many semiconductors fit this description.
There are also other types of excitations, like "trions". These are excitations of two electrons and a hole or two holes and an electron. These are observed, for instance, in monolayer MoS$_2$, where the low dimensionality of the material reduces screening of the electron-hole interaction. Nobody would say that this photoexcitation is an exciton.
The concept of excitons is relevant in any system (solid state, molecular, etc.) where a term involving the electron-hole interaction is needed in the Hamiltonian to adequately explain observations. In many systems it is not, but it also depends on your notion of what is adequate. Unfortunately, I cannot speak to your specific examples. But it is common in molecular systems that the energy level of a state (as measured, e.g., by photoluminescence) is lower than the energy required to excite that state, which might suggest an exciton model to be useful.
